# How can I detect the back button being pressed in QWizard?

Tags: c++, qt, events, wizard, signals-slots

I have a QWizard and I need to perform certain actions each time a wizard page becomes visible. Currently I am doing this in the **validateCurrentPage** function but I have realised that it is only called when the Next button is pressed, not the Back button.

I've tried the **currentIdChanged** and **customButtonClicked** signals but these don't get called either.

Any idea how I can respond to a wizard page that is shown after the Back button is pressed? I must be missing something simple...

Thanks,
Alan

**Edit:** Added code and compiler error as requested by cmannett85

```
QAbstractButton *backButton = button(QWizard::BackButton);
connect(backButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(backClicked));
```

The full error is:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'bool QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QAbstractButton *' to 'const QObject *'

Comment: This error doesn't really make sense unless you forgot to add "#include <QAbstractButton>".

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the cause of the error... sorry I didn't spot it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the back button with [`QAbstractButton *QWizard::button (WizardButton which)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#button) and connect it to a slot.

Example:

```
QAbstractButton *backButton = wizard->button(QWizard::BackButton);
connect(backButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(backClicked()));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd already tried this but I was getting the error "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QAbstractButton *' to 'const QObject *'". If I could get to the back button through ui->... then it would work.

Comment: @AlanSpark There's something else going there as `QAbstractButton` derives from `QObject`, can you add the code you used for that and full compiler error to your question?

Comment: It looks like this is going to do the job, although it seems a bit more complicated than it should be. I'll settle for it for now though! Thanks for your help.